# Woocommerce takes a long time to load and throws my page with a 503 error

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I've been make a wordpress site with woocommerce and works perfectly but when you enter in the wordpress panel in woocommerce > Desktop, for see your sells, Leaderboards, etc, it takes a long time to load and the website down with a 503 error, i can't access to the website for 3 minutes. This can happen in the entire woocommerce plugin but in this section is where this problem happens the most. The server use all the 512 Mb and all the I / O that is 1 Mb.

In the Cpanel> Metrics> CPU and Concurrent Connection Usage> Snapshot, the table shows two CMD / usr / sbin / httpd -k start with 225 MB of ram each.

I've been reinstall the woocomerce plugin, i increased the php memory and wordpress memory but doesn't work. Anyone had this problem?

Thank for your support.

**EDIT 1**

My debug log in wp-content is:

```
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: items in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1251
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1226
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1240
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1258
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1298
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1314
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1319
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1324
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1329
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1356
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: items in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1251
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1226
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1240
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1258
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1298
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1314
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)m/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1319
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1324
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1329
[12-Jun-2020 22:49:54 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/vmgcwv3crvl0/public_html/(mydomain)/wp-includes/rest-api.php on line 1356
```

**EDIT 2**

PHP version: 7.4.5

Woocommerce versión: 4.2.0

Wordpress version: 5.4.2

rest-api code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zoqwjhuuwny1oi8/rest-api.php?dl=0

I see this [solution](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-admin/pull/4377/files) and now i don't have errors in debug_log but when enter to see the woocommerce statics my website goes out but now with 524 error.

In the google console i have this errors when i woocommerce load the statics:
[image: Error image]

Comment: did you turn on error log in wp-config? and check what error says. paste the error

Comment: Sorry, I update the post with debug log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to change the theme  make it default theme and see is that work & add define( ‘WP_DEBUG’, true ); and define( ‘WP_DEBUG_LOG’, true ); to “wp-config.php” file. This will create a “debug.log” file in wp-content folder. i hope that can help you

Comment: ok just try to disable api rest woocomerce -> setting->advanced -> api rest  disable it and see if that work

Comment: The api rest from the beginning was not activated but I tried to activate it and I continue with the same problem in both cases (if it is activated or deactivated).

Comment: Undefined index: items means the variable i think if you  add this  !isset()  it will be ok

Comment: My php version is 7.4.5 and the code for the rest-api is (before apply !isset()) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zoqwjhuuwny1oi8/rest-api.php?dl=1). I apply the !isset() but doesn't work.I see the same problem on github [here](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-admin/pull/4377) and i have to add `'items' => array('type' => 'string',),` in woocommerce plugin and i don't have the errors anymore in the debug_log but i have the same issue when i see the statics in the wordpres panel my website goes down but now with 524 error.

Comment: I update the post with an image the google console when woocommerce load the statics.

Comment: hello hello that clear now you probelm wc analytique go in plugin folder and creat a new plugin inside creat disable-woocommerce-admin.php  
add_filter( 'woocommerce_admin_disabled', '__return_true' );

Comment: and activate the plugin now

Comment: So the woocommerce admin is the problem. I've disable the plugin and works, but now i haven't the benefits of this plugin, i suppose that in a next update they will solve this problem.I will open a new problem in the woocommerce admin github repository. Thank you for your support.

Comment: happy for you but i think the problem in your theme

Comment: What you mean? I use Astra for the woocommerce, how to configure Astra theme? or what is the problem whith this theme?

Comment: try to make last version of the theme

Comment: i have the last version of the astra theme.

Comment: Somebody open a issue with the same problems that i have. [Link of the issue](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-admin/issues/3943).

Comment: WC Admin makes too many ‘GET requests’ this is your issue do you  have many orders ?

Comment: chedck this code to limite thos request   
 https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce-admin/blob/master/client/wc-api/constants.js#L13

Comment: The online store is still under development so I don't have any order.

Comment: ok take back up of product and page and do another wordpress it's better

Comment: I recently i moved the woocommerce site to Siteground and works perfectly, i don't have the problem anymore, woocommerce admin works in siteground. i reinstall woocomerce in godaddy but I still had the same problem so when moved to siteground, the problems were solved.

Comment: yeap but next time try to chose a hosting isolated read carefully  there proposition